# Issue with PHP Login script

Tags: php, mysql

Before mentioning my question, I will first write down my login script here.

My Login page script:-

```
<?php
include_once('core.inc.php'); 
if(loggedin())
{
header('Location:index.php');
} else {
include_once('connection.php');
if($_POST['parse']=="login")
    {
    if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))
        {
            $username=$_POST['username'];
            $password=$_POST['password'];
            if(!empty($username) && !empty($password))
            {
            $username=strip_tags($username);
            $username=mysql_real_escape_string($username);
            $password=strip_tags($password);
            $password=mysql_real_escape_string($password);
            $hash_password=md5($password); /* It will encrypt the password enterd by user in to 15 digit combination of character and number. Then the sql command will be generated to find the appropriate user according to their login details. It will search for the user details in the user table. */
            $query="SELECT `id` FROM `user` WHERE `Email`='".$username."' AND `Hash_password`='".$hash_password."' AND `Approved`=1";
            $query_run=mysql_query($query);
            $mysql_num_rows=mysql_num_rows($query_run);
            if($mysql_num_rows == 1)
                {
                $user_id=mysql_result($query_run,0,'id');
                $_SESSION['user_id']= $user_id; 
                header('Location:http://leadstool.net/profile/index.php');
                } else {
                        print "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
                        print "alert('Email Id and Password Combination is wrong.')";
                        print "</script>";
                }
            }
        }
    }// loop for parse ends here
}// 1st condition ends here
?>
```

And the core.inc.php file script is:-

```
<?php
ob_start();
include_once('connection.php');
session_start();
$current_file=$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))
{
$http_referer=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
}
function loggedin()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['user_id']))
    {
    return true;
    } else {
    return false;
    }
}

function getfield($field)
{
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['user_id']))
    {
    $query="SELECT `$field` FROM `user` WHERE `id`='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";
    if($query_run=mysql_query($query))
        {
        if($query_result= mysql_result($query_run, 0,$field))
            {
            return $query_result;
            }
        }
    }

}
?>
```

First of all let me explain the program flow of the above code:
Step-1: User will enter his/ her Login details. And if the Email Id and Password combination match is found then the user session will be created.

Step-2: Now, after creating a session for the user, user will be instantly redirected to the his/her profile page.

Step-3: Since the user is logged in so, if he/she will click on the home button in menu bar. Then user will be redirected back to the profile page only. Since the user session is already in active mode. Hence user is not allowed to see the content of the home page instead of this user will be redirected back to the profile page only.

But the issue here is, if the user is logged in for the first time his/her session is not created properly. So, once the user is clicking on that ***home*** button he/she is redirected back to the home page. But it is not suppose to happen. User must be redirected back to the profile page only. Since, in the home page script, i am checking for the user session details and if the session is active user will be redirected back to the profile page only.

But the main issue starts here, If the same user is trying to logging with the same login details. Then the the code has no issue. It means, if allow a single user to login twice at the same time then the code has no issue. So, now i wanted to know where is the bug?

So, Here is my question is:-
Q1. Whether my script got some issue or it is a browser compatibility issue ?
Q2. In either case what are the possible solutions ?

I have tried to explain the problem. But if still i'm missing something here then please go to the website ***http://www.leadstool.net***. After successful registration try to login once and click on the ***leadstool*** button in the menu bar. I guess you will find the bug there.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: okay .. thanx I will keep in mind :)

Answer (score 0):

The possibilities are that your script might have some error. It would have been better if you had uploaded the code of your home page. Anyway let me tell the possible solution.

Please check if your Home page has the following codes in it:

```
    include_once('core.inc.php');         
    session_start();
    if(!loggedin())
    {
        header('Location:[your homepage url]');
    }
```

or use the following code.

```
    session_start();
    if(isset['user_id'])
    {
        header('Location:[your homepage url]');
    }
```